# Cordova: Calling JS method from JAVA, when app is closed

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

**Problem Statement:**

I've a scenario where I want to call JS method from JAVA plugin side code. The catch is App is closed.

**Scenarios**

Plugin JAVA code     calling JS     calculate based on App Data
<========>
Do Action based        output
on output data

App running or Background                                   App Closed

WebView available                                   WebView not available
We can call JS method from JAVA                     We can call JS method from JAVA by createing
temporary WebView instance
But can't use the method sitting with App code

Tried

1. Called JS method while app running or background
2. Created temporary WebView runtime and executed JS statements

I hope I'm able to explain the scenario clearly.

Can someone have any idea on this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you most certainly need a [Cordova plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/hybrid/plugins/), because this is the only way to execute native Java code and invoke Android/iOS APIs.

Also, Android and iOS will generally suspend apps in the background, so you need a plugin like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-background-mode-fixed) to prevent the app from sleeping. However, the stores could detect this and reject your app because they are against this type of behaviour.

Apps sent to background must be suspended to prevent battery drain, except apps where some kind of real time service is involved. As a side note, my S7 even suspends the WhatsApp live location sharing when sent to background, so if even they couldn't manage to keep it active... good luck with your app.